# How do style arbitrary XML as a list with CSS?

Tags: css, xml

I want this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="foo.css" type="text/css"?>
<foo>
  <bar>Item1</bar>
  <bar>Item2</bar>
</foo>
```

To display in a browser as if foo was ol and bar was li in HTML.   Is this possible?  This doesn't work:

```
foo {
 display: block;
}
bar { 
 display: list-item;
 list-item-style: decimal;
}
```

But I know something's working because the items are broken into separate lines by setting the display style to list-item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works, you're just not seeing it, methinks.

First, make sure the file is `.xml`.

Next, I've never heard of a CSS property `list-item-style`. Change it to:

```
bar { 
 display: list-item;
 list-style: decimal;
}
```

... and then add some `margin` and `padding`:

```
foo {
 display: block;
}
bar { 
 display: list-item;
 list-style: square;
 padding-left:20px;
 margin-left:20px;
}
```

Comment: margin-left was it, thanks! list-stlye-type can from here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_list.asp

Comment: @Tommy - You should accept the answer then ;) See [the tick](http://www.mitalia.net/images/so/accepted_tick.png)?